# prove that $\{ a_n \}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

for $n\geq1$, $|a_n| < 2$ and  $|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2|$.

 prove that $\{ a_n \}$ is convergent.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b) $

Comment: where is your try?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n \geq 1$, we have $$\left\lvert a_{n +2} -a_{n +1} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{8} \left\lvert a_{n +1} +a_{n} \right\rvert \left\lvert a_{n +1} -a_{n} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{8} \left( \left\lvert a_{n +1} \right\rvert +\left\lvert a_{n} \right\rvert \right) \left\lvert a_{n +1} -a_{n} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{2} \left\lvert a_{n +1} -a_{n} \right\rvert \, \text{.}$$

It follows that $$\left\lvert a_{n +1} -a_{n} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{2^{n -1}} \left\lvert a_{2} -a_{1} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{2^{n -1}} \left( \left\lvert a_{2} \right\rvert +\left\lvert a_{1} \right\rvert \right) \leq \frac{1}{2^{n -3}}$$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Therefore, for all $q > p \geq 1$, we have $$\left\lvert a_{q} -a_{p} \right\rvert \leq \sum_{k = p}^{q -1} \left\lvert a_{k +1} -a_{k} \right\rvert \leq \sum_{k = p}^{q -1} \frac{1}{2^{k -3}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{p -2}} \, \text{.}$$

This proves that the sequence $\left( a_{n} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ is Cauchy and hence converges.

Answer (score 1):

Because $a^2−b^2=(a−b)(a+b),$
$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le \frac1 8 |a_{n+1} + a_n| \bullet|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| $$ $$= \frac1 8^2 |a_{n+1} + a_n| \bullet|a_{n}^2 - a_{n-1}^2|$$
$$= \frac1 8^3 |a_{n+1} + a_n| \bullet|a_{n} + a_{n-1}|\bullet|a_{n} - a_{n-1}|$$
$$...$$
$$=\frac18^n \prod^n |a_{n+1} + a_n|$$

And since $|a_n| \lt 2$, $$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le \frac18^n \prod^n |a_{n+1} + a_n| \le \frac18^n \bullet 4^n = \frac 12^n$$ and it converges